# Finding the Fourier Transform of $\frac{sinx}{x^2}$

Tags: fourier-transform, convolution

I have been given the fourier transform for $f\left(x\right) = 1/x$ as

$\hat f = -iπ \,{\rm sgn}\left(x\right)$

I need to find the Fourier Transform of $\frac{\sin x}{x^2}$ using convolution somehow

My attempt was to use $f\left(x\right) = 1/x$ and find some $g\left(x\right)$ such that $f*g\left(x\right)$ would be  $\frac{\sin x}{x^2}$ but I cannot find such a $g\left(x\right)$

Comment: One possible approach if you insist on using convolutions: If you know the Fourier transform of $f(x) = \frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ and $g(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ then $\mathcal{F}[f(x)g(x)] = \hat{f}*\hat{g}$. To find the Fourier transform of $\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ you can use the same trick: you know that of $\frac{1}{x}$ and that of $\sin(x)$ follows directly from the definition.

Comment: @Winther Thank you! I didn't realise that the convolution of the fourier transforms is the FT of the product of the functions but this makes sense from the definition of the inverse FT!